# I'm not able to code my raspberry pi b+ model as a receiver for receiving binary data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I'm new to python and I wish to know how to fetch my binary data coming from another raspberry pi sender. I hope that my logic is correct. If you can spot any errors please do let me know. And please do answer the question with proper codes. Thank you.

here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(31, GPIO.IN)
a=[]
 # here is the problem when i can't fetch all the binary data from the GPIO pin 31 which is a clock pin of raspberry pi b+ model
a=GPIO.read() # should receive binary data which is not happening
for i in range(len(a)):
        print 'a'
        if GPIO.input(31)==True:
            a.append(1)
        if GPIO.input(31)== False:
            a.append(0)
print a #all binary data should be collected and be printed over here
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: are you attempting to recieve serial data from another pi? there are a lot better ways to do this, look at pyserial

Comment: This question may be better asked on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Comment: this is not a serial communication but here i m trying to send binary data from one rpi to another rpi where my rpi should read data and therefore behave as a receiver picking binary data from sender rpi @JamesKent

Comment: @JamesKent actually i m keeping TFT screen on the receiver side of the rpi to display data and i can't use UART pins ... but an I2C pin 27 & 28 is available to be used and i don't know how to use it .. can pyserial be used on a clock pin like pin 31

Comment: you could look at i2c for comms, or you could look into connecting them together with a network (cable of wifi) and then using sockets, but if it has to be done via GPIO pins i'd recommend you look at this library: http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/ this runs a system daemon so your program doesn't need root permissions for the GPIO, and has built in funtions to do serial links on any GPIO pin, so takes the difficult bits out of the way.

Comment: We are using python programming language so please send us some links regarding python libraries @James Kent